# How do you pass a variable to another script and/or scene in Unity?

Tags: c#, variables, unity-game-engine

I am working on a game that requires a score. I would like to pass my variable to another scene in c#. I've tried lots of solutions but none of them have worked! I have a public static variable as my score and I would like to pass it to a lose screen.

Comment: Why don't you just create a gui panel for losing which is set to invisible and get's shown on losing?

Comment: Please, don't use `unity` tag if you're referring to Unity game engine. It's generally a good idea to read tag descriptions before using them.

Comment: @MaxYankov Ok, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make an Empty GameObject and Use DontDestroyOnLoad() at the Empty GameObject and store any data u want to pass to another scene in the script attached to the EmptyGameObject and retrieve data from the EmptyGameObject in next Scene.

Refer following video on youtube to see this concept in action:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VauchY1uIB4

Comment: Surprised I didn't think of that one.. It worked great. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 6):

PlayerPrefs is a **very bad habit** to store data between scenes. It has been designed to store data between game executions, not scenes ; because it will persist your data locally on your computer.

In the case where you want to pass data between scenes, it could be a good idea to make a GameManager, as explained in one [tutorial](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/projects/2d-roguelike/gamemanager) on the official website.

The idea is:

- Put a "loader" game object on each of your scenes, which will instantiate the GameManager if it's not
- GameManager maintains a static reference to itself, so you can access it everywhere (after the awake method) by calling *GameManager.instance.myScore* (to be sure that loader has the time to instantiate it).

Just take a look at the tutorial, it's very well explained. But do **not** use [PlayerPrefs](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html) to pass data through your scenes.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you use playerprefs: http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/PlayerPrefs.html

example, in a scene you set the variable:
PlayerPrefs.SetInt("Score",value);

in another scene you get it
PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Score",0);

The 0 on the second call is the default value, if it does not exist, it will return you 0